# Reading and drawing a pixel font in ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fonts

I've created a small pixel-font that I want to use in a Flash game.

Each letter is 6 pixels tall, and 7 pixels wide.  I've saved a PNG file with all the letters from A-Z lined up next to each other.

Basically, I'd like to be able to have a system where I point to the PNG file and say "A is position (0,0) to (7,6), B is position (7,0) to (14, 6), etc" then render those individually on the screen as letters in my font.

I was inspired to do this by watching (the creator of Minecraft) Notch do it in [a video of him making Megagun](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZV-AFnCkRLY).

So, has anyone done anything like this before? Is there a simple library that will let me do it already?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is called a "Sprite sheet", and there are a ton of project out there that do this sort of thing. The best starting place is probably [Ben Silvis' AS3: Intro to Using Sprite Sheets](http://www.bensilvis.com/?p=229). Also check out [AS3: SpriteSheet Class – Extracting Sprites](http://www.bensilvis.com/?p=317).

There are also tools for creating sprite sheets from flash animations, such as [SWFSheet by Keith Peters](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2939)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the information. I'll check the links and see if I get something working.